# DropDownList Two SqlDataSources

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, sqldatasource

I have a DropDownList as a TemplateField in a DetailsView. I want to populate this DropDownList with all possible options that will be pulled from one SqlDataSource while assigning the selected value of the DropDownList to the current value coming from the SqlDataSource that the DetailsView is bound to.  So something like:

```
<asp:DetailsView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="Serial">
           /* Here is where I need to bind the dropdown to data source 2 so that All serials are available while selecting it's current value from data source 1.
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
    SelectCommand = "Select SerialNumber From Equipment Where EquipID = @EquipID">
   <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue=""
            Name="EquipID" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Values[EquipID]" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2"
    SelectCommand = "Select SerialNumber From Equipment">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `DataSourceID` of the `DropDownList` to the data source that populates the options, and then assign the `SelectedValue` to the current value from the data source bound to the `DetailsView`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Serial" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource#"
    DataValueField="..." DataTextField="..."
    SelectedValue='<%#Bind("MYFIELDNAME")%>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Where `MYFIELDNAME` comes from the data source bound to the `DetailsView` representing the current value for that record.